# CentOS or Scientific Linux 6 for Storage-Home-Server?

Tags: linux, centos

I planned to use CentOS 6 on my new Home-Server, but it is still not available.
On my search for alternatives I discovered Scientific Linux 6 which is also binary compatible with RHEL.

Is there much difference between this two distributions?

Answer (score 1):

From what I'm aware, CentOS is simply a recompilation with all RedHat trademarking and other IP removed, whereas Scientific has had packages added/removed/altered. This is my understanding, and not guaranteed accurate. If it was me, and I wanted a RHEL6 compatible, I'd wait for CentOS.

Comment: If you read the page that describes the modifications in ScientificLinux, the mods are very minimal.  Don't knock it 'till you try it ;)